# @HTML.ActionLink stops working when new htmlAttribute is added

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

After adding htmlAttributes for `@HTML.ActionLink` it throws an error:

> "Cannot resolve action Index"

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ","Index",routeValues: "Home", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "black" })
```

Without that attribute `ActionLink` works fine:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home")
```

Comment: replace the empty text (First param) with some valid text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a non empty text as the first parameter so that it will be shown as the link text.  Also i think you are using the helper method incorrect.

This should work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index",  "Home", null,  new { @class = "black" })
```

If you want to pass some route values (which will be come querystring key-values), replace the `null` with an anonymous object.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index",  "Home", new { id=123} ,  new { @class = "black" })
```